# MVC - Keep model consistent with DB

Tags: php, rest, model-view-controller

I'm a front-end developer who are trying to write his first back-end RESTful webapplication in php/mysql.

What it's confusing me is to figure out how the model works. In fe programming, usually wrote in angularjs, model is often a service that provides data from a webservice. Model doesn't exists from itself, services provide it only when they get some calls from controllers.

In backend scenario I have a DB which stocks data, and from there I have to retrieve data which will compose my model.
The problem to me is: data are being updated continously from each client which talks with this backend, so I need to keep my model consistent with a DB that are continuously changing. I had use an implementation similar to frontend, with model that have being created only when controllers commands some interactions with it, and this solves the problem to me.

But a friend of mine (which is very skilled) told me that this approach is wrong, and that model have to be independent to controllers. But, if DB changes, how do I get aware of this and then update my model?

I hope to have being clear

Comment: Why not use `push` or `Web Sockets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the backend MVC, the model is usually divided in three parts: Domain, DAO and Service.

Domain is a representation of your data, in the case a class with only attributes.
The DAO is a class that implements the access to the database (or files etc). Usually there are a DAO class for each Domain class and the methods receive or return objects of these classes.
And the service is what the controller access to talk to the model, it implements high level methods.

In that way you can access information of the model in all controllers. Every time you need information you call a service's method like 'getUsers()'.

Comment: Note: Most of the time there is no 'bind' like in Angular, you need to update manually.

Comment: But is there any place where objects produced by DAO persist? A piece of code which holds them for any future query from Service layer? Or every request from higher layer involves DAO (which in order to satisy it make a SQL query)?

Comment: No, every request need a call to DAO.

Comment: So, this leads me to the intial point: model exists only when it get "invoked". DAO interrogate dbms and provides result. Data do not persists in this layer, right?

Comment: Right. But it's as if the database were part of the Model.

Comment: If you need "realtime update" you need "push or Web Sockets" as said by @tftd.